# How do I calculate the chance of getting a number with a certain probability?

Tags: probability

Lets say I am filling out a scantron. I have a 1 in 4 chance of answering each question correctly. How do I calculate the odds of getting over a 65% on the test?

Comment: The odds/probability depends on the number of questions in the test.